# loop through array, output each item to new line

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through an array and write each item to a new line on the click of a button. At present when I click the the button nothing happens.

No errors are being shown in the code, where have I gone wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var vehicle = ["G122 IVL", "H151 KEE", "U109 FIJ"];

  var cameraOne = function() {

    $.each(vehicle, function(index, value) {
      $('#c1').html('<p>' + value + '</p>');
    });
  };

  $('#cameraOne').click(function() {
    cameraOne();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="cameraOne" value="Camera One" />
  <div id="c1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: And, your question is..?

Comment: You have a scope problem not to mention that you're overwriting your c1's HTML every time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the contents of `#c1` with each new line, when you want to append:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var vehicle = ["G122 IVL", "H151 KEE", "U109 FIJ"];

  var cameraOne = function() {
    $('#c1').empty();

    $.each(vehicle, function(index, value) {
      // use .text() instead of just writing the value to the <p> tag, so we're safe
      // if the value contains <, etc.
      $('#c1').append($('<p>').text(value));
    });
  };

  $('#cameraOne').click(function() {
    cameraOne();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="cameraOne" value="Camera One" />
  <div id="c1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, what kind of scenario would better use .html()

Comment: When you want to replace the entire contents of an element, all at once, with known-valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var vehicle = ["G122 IVL", "H151 KEE", "U109 FIJ"];

var cameraOne = function() {

    $.each(vehicle, function(index, value) {
        $('#c1').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
    });
};

$('#cameraOne').click(function() {
        cameraOne();
    });
});
```

`html` overwrites the contents, so you get only the last value. Use `append` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 'html' `$('#c1').html('<p>' + value + '</p>');` which is causing the line to be overwritten each time a value is found, you should use 'append' `$('#c1').append('<p>' + value + '</p>');` to create a new line for each value.